# Is there any way to pause Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Since I can't keep colab running without interracting with it, I would like to pause my session. If I press the stop button, I'll lose what's been done in the running cell so far. Is there some way to avoid this?

Comment: try to use an infinite loop like infinite while loop. It will keep running

Comment: I think there's a limit of like 90 minutes, then Colab asks if you're still there?

Comment: It will ask you if you have closed the connection(closed the tab or the laptop) or not doing anything, so running an infinite loop and keeping the laptop on would keep it going and when you wanna start working again just stop the loop and start doing the old work, try this

Comment: That wouldn't work because Colab has a limited run time before it disconnects (to save resources),